# Loop to beginning

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, do-while

Hi so I'm still learning C and here's what I came up with. My problem is that it wont start to the beginning if the user inputted the variable 'number' to less than or equal to 0. Any tips? Also mind if I ask, how to loop to the beginning when you use a function?

```
void main() {

    int x = 0, y = 0, m, n, number, life = 4;
    char choice;
    int a[R][C] = { {0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0} };

    do {
        printf("\t\t\t      Welcome to my game");
        Sleep(2000);
        printf("\n\n   This game is all about guessing where your number is located in the matrix");
        Sleep(2000);
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tOnly 1 player\n");
        Sleep(2000);
        printf("\n\n   You are betting your own very life! \t\t\tYou have 5 tries");
        Sleep(1000);
        printf("\n\nEnter your number: ");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        system("cls");
        if (number <= 0) {
            system("cls");
            printf("Only positive numbers allowed");
            printf("\nRetry? Y/N: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%c", &choice);
            fflush(stdin);
            if (choice == 'n' || choice == 'N') {
                system("cls");
                printf("Thanks for playing");
                break;
            }
            system("cls");
            break;
        }
        display(a);
        printf("\n\nInputted number is %d", number);
        printf("\n\nYour number is now being placed at a random location");
        printf("\n\nGuess where your number is located (row) (column)");
        printf("\n\nNote: Enter only numbers 1-4 or else you'll be wrong");
        printf("\n\nEnter coordinates: ");
        scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
        printf("\n");
        placingguess(a, number, m, n, life);
        break;
    } while (choice != 'n' || choice != 'N');

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Technically you have undefined behavior in the code, doing `fflush(stdin)` is not a defined operation. Some standard libraries allows it as an extension but it's not something you should get into a habit of doing if you want to write portable code.

Comment: Do you really find relevant to put the program to sleep for 7000 seconds? Further on, `fflush` on `stdin` causes undefined behavior. What is `cls`?

Comment: As for your problem, what are those `break` statement doping there in the loop? You *do* know what [`break`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/break) inside a loop does?'

Comment: @user3078414 `cls` is the DOS command to clear screen

Comment: @user3078414: `Sleep()` most likley is the Win32 API's sleeper function, which takes *milli*-seconds (mind the capital `S`). `cls` is the DOS/Windows command interpreter's command to clear the console.

Comment: @user3078414 It's really not that relevant to put the sleep command. It's just there for the design. Since my teacher said to make it more exciting and I don't know how to make it more exciting :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `continue` instead of `break`.

```
    }
    system("cls"); 
    continue; 
}
display(a);
```

Comment: I never knew there was a command such as 'continue'. Now it's working! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have used

```
break;
```

- `break` - exit the current `while` \ `for` \ `do`-`while` ...
- `continue` - next iteration.

The first `break`; is just fine, because the user enter `N` to retry,
the second needs to be `continue`!

Comment: Thanks! now it's working. Never knew there was a command 'continue' until now.